# Test Printing On Solaris

Tags: solaris, printing

How can i test a printer connection by sending some text to a printer named "myprinter" from the shell?

Answer (score 1):

```
whoami|lpr -Pmyprinter
```

Best printer name I have seen is "nuts" - you do lpr -Pnuts to print. :)